# Representing numbers through dice

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This question came from an entrance exam I wrote for TU Darmstadt today. I can't remember the exact phrasing , but I'll try paraphrasing

> Can we create 2024 by keeping  six sided dices in a horizontal row with the constraint that we can only keep faces with same dots in contact? The value of each dice is the sum of the numbers on each seeable side. Bonus: Which numbers can we represent in the scheme as described?
>
> Hint: Opposite side always add up to seven

Example set up to understand question:

> ## Example-1:
>
> A single dice laid on a table with six down, has a value of 1+2+3+4+5
> Picture:
>
> [image]
>
> Explanation: We can see all the side except six, so that's the answer

> ## Example-2 :
>
> [image]
>
> In the above, the value is $2 \times 6 + 2\times (3+4)+ 2 +5 $
>
> Explanation:The first term of sum is from the faces at ends, the $ 2 \times 7 $ comes from 3 and the 4 opposite to it (happens twice), and 5 and 2 comes from the top faces

I think this question has something to do about number theory... but I am not really sure how to go above it honestly.

Comment: @lulu- I think you just add up all the individual faces. For some reason they collected a few of the faces in pairs for their example, which I think might confuse people.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant @JonathanZ. You add up all the individual faces that you can see

Comment: The bad notation has been corrected in an edit, I'll delete my prior comments.

Comment: Suggestion: Write out all eight terms in your second example, and put them in two groups, one for each of the dice.

Comment: I suggest:  work out the full list of values assuming a small number of dice.  For one die this is easy.  Already for two dice, it gets a bit hard to enumerate.  Perhaps a recursive scheme can be set up, but it's not obvious.

Comment: I think the pairing off faces that sum to seven is part of your solution approach, but I'd leave that out of the problem specification.

Comment: Which intermediate dice? It is not neccesarily 14 @CalvinLin It is however, minimum of seven for value of intermediate dive

Comment: @CalvinLin, from the examples it is clear that of the intermediate dices, two opposite faces and one topmost face will be counted. I don't see how their value will be ever $14$, it will be between $8$ and $13$ inclusive.

Comment: @Sahaj  Ah, I didn't get that the face side down isn't included. Deleted comments.

Comment: Hint: Suppose the leftmost face is 1, and we use $n = 2k$ an even number of dice. Then, there is a solution iff we can solve for $n= a+b+c+d, 9a+10b+11c+12d + 2 = 2024$, which almost certainly we can.

Answer (score 1):

Any configuration can be expanded on the right by a pair of dice without changing the side $k$ seen on the right. The front and back of the pair add to $14$, and the tops can independently show any number other than $k$ and $7-k$. The possible sums of the front, back and top are thus

$k=1$ or $6$ (leaving $2,3,4,5$):  $18$–$24$,
$k=2$ or $5$ (leaving $1,3,4,6$):  $16$, $18$–$24$, $26$,
$k=3$ or $4$ (leaving $1,2,5,6$):  $16$–$18$, $20$–$22$, $24$–$26$.

We can regard the possible visible sums of the pairs as coin denominations in a [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). [Here](http://mathsjavascript.free.fr/frobenius_9_page.html)’s a calculator for such problems. The result is that the following numbers can be expressed as non-empty sums of these sums (but actually it’s not too much work to figure this out by hand):

$k=1$ or $6$:  $18$–$24$, $36$–$48$, $54$–$\infty$
$k=2$ or $5$:  $16$, $18$–$24$, $26$, $32$, $34$–$\infty$
$k=3$ or $4$:  $16$–$18$, $20$–$22$, $24$–$26$, $32$–$\infty$

That solves the $2024$ problem, since you can take a die and add an appropriate strings of pairs to reach $2024$.

To solve the “bonus” problem, consider the configurations we can add these pairs to. If we start without dice, we have to count that as $2k$, since it will leave two additional sides that show $k$ exposed. If we start with one die, that die can show one of these sums:

$k=1$ or $6$:  $16$, $17$, $18$, $19$
$k=2$ or $5$:  $15$, $17$, $18$, $20$
$k=3$ or $4$:  $15$, $16$, $19$, $20$

Together, that yields the following options for the starting configuration:

$k=1$ or $6$:  $2$, $12$, $16$, $17$, $18$, $19$
$k=2$ or $5$:  $4$, $10$, $15$, $17$, $18$, $20$
$k=3$ or $4$:  $6$, $\hphantom{0}8$, $15$, $16$, $19$, $20$

Adding these options to the ones for the pairs generates the following sums:

$k=1$ or $6$:  $20$–$26$, $30$–$\infty$ 
$k=2$ or $5$:  $20$, $22$–$\infty$ 
$k=3$ or $4$:  $22$–$\infty$

Thus, all numbers greater than $19$ can be generated by adding some non-zero number of pairs to a starting configuration, and a single die can generate the numbers from $15$ to $20$, so all numbers greater than $14$ can be generated.

Comment: Where did you get fourteen from? You get only one guaranteed 7

Comment: @trystwithfreedom: I'm not sure what you mean by "guaranteed". Each of the two dice shows a front and a back side, and for each of them those two opposite sides add to $7$, so those four sides together add to $14$.